# I want my elements to fadein and fade out and then the page to close and load another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Not sure if its possible however what I would like to achieve is the following:

My element with the class ".splashscreenlogo" to show when the document is ready, I would like it to show for 2.5 seconds before it fades out and then my element with a class ".scene" fades in for a further 3 seconds before it fades out again. Once this has finished the whole page redirects to another html page.

Current html:

```
<div class="scene">
  <svg 
  version="1.1" 
  id="dc-spinner" 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
  x="0px" y="0px"
  width:"38"
  height:"38"
  viewBox="0 0 38 38" 
  preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"
  >
  <text x="14" y="21" font-family="Monaco" font-size="2px" style="letter-spacing:0.6" fill="grey">LOADING
     <animate 
       attributeName="opacity"
       values="0;1;0" dur="1.8s"
       repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </text>
  <path fill="#2AA198" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="0.5027" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M5.203,20
            c0-8.159,6.638-14.797,14.797-14.797V5C11.729,5,5,11.729,5,20s6.729,15,15,15v-0.203C11.841,34.797,5.203,28.159,5.203,20z">
  <animateTransform
        attributeName="transform"
        type="rotate"
        from="0 20 20"
        to="360 20 20"
        calcMode="spline"
        keySplines="0.4, 0, 0.2, 1"
        keyTimes="0;1"
        dur="2s"
        repeatCount="indefinite" />      
   </path>

  <path fill="#859900" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="0.5027" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M7.078,20
  c0-7.125,5.797-12.922,12.922-12.922V6.875C12.763,6.875,6.875,12.763,6.875,20S12.763,33.125,20,33.125v-0.203
  C12.875,32.922,7.078,27.125,7.078,20z">
   <animateTransform
      attributeName="transform"
      type="rotate"
      from="0 20 20"
      to="360 20 20"
      dur="1.8s"  
      repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </path>
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="splashscreenlogo">
  <img src="logo_splashscreen.png" alt="Splashscreen logo" style="width:100%;height:auto">
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
html body {
  background: url("Splashscreen.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  font: 14px/21px Monaco, sans-serif;
  color: none;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
          text-size-adjust: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
html body a, html body a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFffF;
}
html body h4 {
  margin: 0;
  color: #666;
}

.scene {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-perspective: 600;
          perspective: 600;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}
.scene svg {
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
}
.splashscreenlogo{
  position: absolute;
  top: 46%;
  left: 36%;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What you can do is that you use Javascript. You do your animations with javasscript (or with css and after a certain time you say to javascript go to another page).  with javascript you can so to another page with `window.location = page`

Comment: I would like to do this with JS if that was possible however I have no experience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try to use SVG's **onend** event and the **repeatCount** to form a counter to call a redirecting function like the following:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="dc-spinner" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" width:"38" height:"38" viewBox="0 0 38 38" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
   <script src="text/javascript">
    <![CDATA[
    function redirect()
    {
      alert("Redirecting.");
    }
   ]]>
  </script> 
  <text x="14" y="21" font-family="Monaco" font-size="2px" style="letter-spacing:0.6" fill="grey">
  LOADING
  <animate 
  attributeName="opacity"
  values="0;1;0" dur="1.8s"
  repeatCount="2" onend="redirect()"/>
</text>
<path fill="#2AA198" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="0.5027" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M5.203,20c0-8.159,6.638-14.797,14.797-14.797V5C11.729,5,5,11.729,5,20s6.729,15,15,15v-0.203C11.841,34.797,5.203,28.159,5.203,20z">
<animateTransform
  attributeName="transform"
  type="rotate"
  from="0 20 20"
  to="360 20 20"
  calcMode="spline"
  keySplines="0.4, 0, 0.2, 1"
  keyTimes="0;1"
  dur="2s"
  repeatCount="indefinite" />
</path>
<path fill="#859900" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="0.5027" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M7.078,20c0-7.125,5.797-12.922,12.922-12.922V6.875C12.763,6.875,6.875,12.763,6.875,20S12.763,33.125,20,33.125v-0.203C12.875,32.922,7.078,27.125,7.078,20z">
<animateTransform
  attributeName="transform"
  type="rotate"
  from="0 20 20"
  to="360 20 20"
  dur="1.8s"  
  repeatCount="indefinite" />
</path>
</svg>
```

[DEMO Here](http://codepen.io/tejzpr/pen/KpPEKg)

You can also try modifying the **dur** and the **repeatCount** attributes in the **animate** tag to match your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

assuming you have JQuery since you mentioned in tags,

use this to achieve what you want.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //hiding initially
    $('.scene').hide();
    //Fade In and delay 2.5 sec then Fade Out
    $('.splashscreenlogo').hide().fadeIn(function() { 
        $(this).delay(2500).fadeOut(function() {
            //Fade In and delay 3 sec then Fade Out
            $('.scene').fadeIn(function() { 
                $(this).delay(3000).fadeOut(function() {
                    //Redirect to any location
                    alert('redirecting to page');
                    window.location = 'http://google.com';
                }); 
            });
        }); 
     }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to go to an other page when the animations are ready.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
     window.location = 'https://www.google.com/';
    },3000);
 })

    /*
    for the time I have choosen a random time. 
    note that the time is in miliseconds 
    one sec has 1000 ms.
    */
```

I used Jquery for this because Idon't know how to detect a page ready but you can search that and apply it tou your code.

For the time you have to count the total time of the animation and replace the 500 miliseconds by your time